# Bootstrap modal popup not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a simple HTML file in which I want to display Bootstrap modal popup. Below is the code for this.

.js file:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/po_ritesh/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/home.css">
    <script src="./js/global.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/home.js"></script>
```

button control:

```
 <button class="myBtn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">test </button>
```

modal div:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            test
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **two** problems:

1. You are missing a library, `bootstrap.js`
2. Your JavaScript files are referenced in the wrong order, causing a JavaScript error. This error prevents your browser from running additional script and the modal code doesn't work.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- this file was missing -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<!-- this file was moved after the jQuery Datatables library was laoded -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to include bootstrap.min.js after the jQuery.js

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not including the bootstrap.js in your code.